# How to use pattern in openapi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-core

I am trying to use pattern to validate the value using regex as below

```
host:
type: string
description: mail.mydomain.com
example: mail.mydomain.com
format: regex
pattern: '\S'
```

while generating a class it is generating as

```
  @ApiModelProperty(
example = "mail.mydomain.com",
required = true,
value = "mail.mydomain.com"
)
public @NotNull @Pattern(
regexp = "\\S"
) String getHost() {
return this.host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
this.host = host;
}
```

it is appending `\\` one more escape character

I have added

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

tried with \ and also quotes nothing worked

Comment: what behaviour are you after and what is the generated class doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using patter with + or * will resolve the issue Ex: pattern: '\S+' or pattern: '\S*'

\S matches only one character, if we have only one character in the field then it will work with \S.

when you want a regex to match multiple characters you need to use + sign, \S+.

Finally able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in pom.xml.
If you are using openApi 3.X and springboot.
Validation on DTO will start working after adding this dependency:

```
pattern: ^\\S$
```

dependency:

```
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>`
```